# Perspective distortion rendering - ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

whenever we apply some transformation using imagemagick convert command , it tries to ensure that the resulting image is of the same size as that of the original image . is there a way such that we get the whole rendered image with transparent/white background .

```
convert -verbose maanavulu_GIST-TLOTKrishna.tif \
        -alpha set -matte -virtual-pixel transparent \
        -distort perspective-projection '1.06,0,0.0,0,2.066,0.0,0.0,0.0' \
        1.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

There's some tricks with `fx` & `repage` hinted at by the [Distorting Usage](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/) documentation. I've found the easiest approach would be to [set](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#distort_viewport) `option:distort:viewport` option to something large enough to capture the whole distortion, then [-trim](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#trim) it to the finial size.

```sh
convert -verbose maanavulu_GIST-TLOTKrishna.tif \
       -alpha set -matte -virtual-pixel transparent \
       -set option:distort:viewport 1000x1000 \
       -distort perspective-projection '1.06,0,0.0,0,2.066,0.0,0.0,0.0' \
       -trim 1.jpg
```